# Access Violation MASM x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am working on a project and I am currently getting an Access Violation in one of my lines. I was wondering if I could get a second opinion on what is wrong. Here is my code (Note, I get the error during runtime, but it does build):

```
.data
BlueTextOnGray = blue + (lightGray * 16)
DefaultColor = lightGray + (black * 16)
arrayD SDWORD 12345678h,1A4B2000h,3434h,7AB9h

fib BYTE 1,2
  BYTE NUMBER_FIBS_TO_COMPUTE dup(0)

prompt  BYTE    "Enter an ending integer: ",0
error   BYTE    "Invalid stopping point! 



.code

main PROC

    mov eax,BlueTextOnGray
    call    SetTextColor
    call    Clrscr          ; Clear the screen
    call    Crlf            ; New line

    mov edx,OFFSET prompt
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt         ; Input integer into EAX
    call    Crlf            ; New line

  lea esi, [fib+2]
  mov cl, NUMBER_FIBS_TO_COMPUTE
@@:
  mov al, [esi-2]
  add al, [esi-1]
  mov [esi], al   ;<------------This is where the error occurs
  inc esi
  loop @B

; here print out the results or examine them with debugger

E1: call    Crlf            ; New line
    call    WaitMsg         ; "Press any key..."
    mov eax,DefaultColor
    call    SetTextColor
    call    Clrscr



exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Is there a rule that I am missing. I have done my research but I cannot seem to find the answer that fits my situation.

Any help would be great!
(Also note that I am not done with it so there might be other mistakes.)

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `fib`? Also note that `loop` uses `ecx` not just `cl` so you should set all 32 bits of it.

Comment: @Jester

`fib` is initialized in the `.data` field.

I added it above in the original post

Comment: What value does `ESI` have when your code faults?  How far beyond `fib` is it?  And what's in ECX, and why didn't you read the second half of Jester's comment?

Comment: Well, the key is that, wherever FIB is, the page is marked as read-only.

Comment: What is `NUMBER_FIBS_TO_COMPUTE`?

Comment: @Ped7g That was just a space in memory to do a set number of loops instead of a user inputed number. I intend on doing a loop based on a number the user inputs, so I already got rid of that variable.

Comment: @Jester I changed the code to use `ecx` and not just `cl` and it seems to be working! Thanks!

Comment: Well, but you use `NUMBER_FIBS_TO_COMPUTE` to reserve memory space for results, so it must be fixed during compilation, and it should be large enough to hold your results, otherwise you will start to overwrite memory where you don't expect it. The symptoms you described would partially fit that situation too in some cases, so it was important to show how you define that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, wherever `fib` points to, which is loaded into `esi`, that memory page is marked as read-only.

Generally, an access violation is caused by attempting to write to a memory location that is marked read-only in the GDT.  A segmentation fault occurs when you attempt to read from a memory location that your process does not have access to at all.

As @Jester points out, you're not paying attention to the high order bits in `ECX`.  While you set your loop control value in `CL`, your loop may run far higher than you intend since `ECX` is unknown.  This would quickly put you into read-only territory in your memory.

Comment: Isn't `fib` correctly defined in the data section?  IDK MASM, but I assumed that was read-write.  I think the code is just running WAY more iterations than expected because of high garbage in ECX like Jester originally pointed out, so it faults when the pointer-increment reaches an unmapped page.

Comment: That might be an issue too, but I can't see where he's setting that to any kind of valid memory region.

Comment: Hmm... Looking again, I think you're right.  Jester has it.